# Correctly showing data in a chart in Excel

Tags: excel

**Problem**

I am finding it difficult to correctly output the data on a scatter graph in Excel. For example, for the month 'January', the number of units shipped equals 15, but this data is shared between two customers, one equaling '12' and the other '3'. The scatter graph is showing two points in the month of January, and the the overall amount.

**Question**

How would I be able to correctly show the data in my scatter graph?

**Image**

https://s17.postimg.org/hu3fzwggv/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: How do you mean correctly? You have two values for series 1 (Jan), 3 and 12, and its showing them both, what do you want it to show?

Comment: I want to show the total amount for each month, I thought I said that sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Chart` to `PivotChart` and you will get aggregated data.
It is in `Charts` section inside `Insert` tab.

Here is a preview of your solution, based on your question and comments:
http://prntscr.com/de0hdv

Comment: It isn't allowing me to select the PivotChart button, why would that be?

Comment: Maybe you have a graph selected? Try selecting your data and then `Insert>PivotChart`. And select whole table, not specific columns only, as it will result in error. After that you can select desired columns in right pane.

Comment: Now it is saying this, I have selected two rows though. https://s18.postimg.org/4olve2pxl/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: Select whole table with headers so that your range is A2:G15 and don't control-select anything else. Then just insert pivot.

Comment: I havent used PivotChart before, what would I do now? https://s11.postimg.org/bpi1kh99f/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: Look at those 4 boxes. Drag `MONTH` in the bottom left one and leave `UNITS` in the bottom right. After that go to `Design` tab and change chart type to `Line` http://prntscr.com/de0u3j. And you should be good to go.

Comment: That has got it, thank you very much for your help Boris.